# Importing multiple CSV files and add filename and row

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I have a directory with multiple csv files and I wish to add the data to a table but also refernce the csv file and row

for example if I have 2 csv files

csv1

```
year;price
2016;£50
2017;£40
```

csv2

```
year;price
2016;£20
2017;£10
```

I would like the table to look like this:

```
File | Row | Year | Price
-------------------------
csv1 | 1   | 2016 | £50
csv1 | 2   | 2017 | £40
csv2 | 1   | 2016 | £20
csv2 | 2   | 2017 | £10
```

So far I can add the data but I am struggling with adding the filename and row, any ideas?

Here is what I have so far

```
Sub Update_Data()
    '~>Define variables
    Dim fPath   As String:      fPath = "C:\Archive\"
    Dim csvFileName    As String

    '~>Start the CSV file listing
    csvFileName = Dir(fPath & "*.csv")

    Do While Len(csvFileName) > 0
        '~>Retrieve the data from the .csv file
        Call Append_CSV_Data(csvFileName)

        '~>Ready next CSV
        csvFileName = Dir
    Loop

End Sub

Sub Append_CSV_Data(csvFileName)
    Dim destCell As Range
    Dim qTable As QueryTable
    Dim wSheet As Worksheet

    Set destCell = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1)

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;" & csvFileName, Destination:=destCell)
        .TextFileStartRow = 2
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

    For Each wSheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each qTable In wSheet.QueryTables
            qTable.Delete
        Next qTable
    Next wSheet
End Sub
```

Comment: You want to iterate through all available .csv files?

Comment: Yes, but the above code already does that. I am struggling with adding the filename and row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe add a little code

```
'get new last row
lastCell = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
'Input file name
Range(Cells(destCell.Row, 1), Cells(lastCell , 1)) = csvFileName
'input row
For i = 1 to lastCell - destCell.Row 
  Cells(destCell.Row + i - 1, 2) = i
Next i
```

Put this after you bring in the query table but before you end the sub.

Comment: I replaced the `Call Append_CSV_Data(csvFileName)` with `msgbox csvFileName` and it's only the file name, not the path that kicks out.  Your code can't do anything with just the name of the file, it needs the location as well.

Comment: My code is working and producing a table without the filename and row column, adding your suggestion does the same

Comment: Sorry I wasn't grasping what you were trying to do well.

Comment: that looks like it should work but I get an error with this line:
Range(Cells(destCell.Row, 1), Cells(lastCell, 1)) = csvFileName

Comment: What error?  Gotta troubleshoot.  Also, did you revert to `Call Append_CSV_Data(csvFileName)`?

Comment: I fixed the error, you missed .row when you reference lastCell, now the problem is that it doesnt count the rows it just adds the same number in all of the row cells. yes I reverted back

Comment: thats it, you must of edited without me realising. Thanks for perserveering with it

Comment: actually sorry thats not quite right, what it is doing is adding the same filename for each and classing each 1 as if it was in 1 file so its going csv1, csv1, csv1, csv1, 1, 2, 3, 4 instead of csv1, csv1, csv2, csv2, 1, 2, 1, 2

Comment: Yeah I realized it was writing the whole range and I revised.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164134/discussion-between-n8-and-chris).

Comment: I fixed it, probably my mistake, I had to add destCell into the loop as t was never resetting

Comment: Thanks for all your help, much appreciated... also I didnt know there was a chat on here lol